# creating elearning system with asp.net mvc for small school

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on a project for one small school organization, for talented sportists, and i will have to create web based e-learning system which will consist from backend and frontend.
Student can log on, see their schedule, their teachers, download some files for school....
Also teachers have ability to log on and do some changes, enter student exam results and upload some files (presentations..)
So my queustion is what is best approach to do this, i am working with asp.net mvc and i think it's solid technology, but i need some workflow design and thoughts how to make it work nicely.

Comment: The problem with your question is that it is a bad question for StackOverflow; SO questions are really for specific issues; your question is all about opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Workflow design

**Take paper and a pen and design it all in paper.**

Design every page that you need to create, with having in your mine that every page have input processing and output.

Then write down what media you may need to create and how much time they can get. Design also your database and the data, and how they interact with the page.

And from all that calculate the time that they take to make them, and take some decisions for what you make of all and what not, and start the develop of it. The more specific is your request the less time they take to made them.